# How to calculate the position in matrix based on screen position

Tags: c#, .net, matrix, xna, pacman

So I'm making a remake of pacman and I'm using XNA and .NET to build it.

I've setup a screen size of 448x576 and a matrix with 28x36, where each position in the matrix responds to 16px by 16px

448 / 16 = 28
576 / 16 = 36

This is how I calculate screen position based off the position in the matrix:

```
public Vector2 GetPositionAt(int col, int row)
    {
        int X = ((col) * 16) + 8;
        int Y = ((row) * 16) + 8;

        return new Vector2(X, Y);
    }
```

the reverse code would be:

```
float col = ((position.X - 8) / 16);
float row = ((position.Y - 8) / 16);

return new MatrixPosition((int)col, (int)row);
```

but this does not work, because the position updates only when the pacman position is at the center of the position in the matrix. I want to make it when it's close to the new point.

Let me explain with pictures (Sorry can't post yet pictures):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7kpH.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float col = ((position.X - 8) / 16);
float row = ((position.Y - 8) / 16);
```

If you substitute position.X = 8 and position.Y = 18:

```
col = ((8 - 8) / 16)
    = 0 / 16
    = 0
row = ((18 - 8) / 16)
    = 10 / 16
    = 0
```

Integers do not work the way you want them to. I understand why you're using -8 to find the centre of the square, but you cannot simply divide correctly using that method.

```
col = position.X / 16
row = position.Y / 16
```

But you'll still need to account for WHERE you are in that cell. Don't over calculate it.